# Quick Content URI Question Android

Tags: android

On Android, I want to make something like `market://ETC` but for my app so it would be like  `method://search?search=WHATEVERHERE` and it'll open one of my activities and put an extra.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanna make something like market://ETC but for my app so it would be like method://search?search=WHATEVERHERE and it'll open one of my activities and put an extra.

Please don't. Even Google admits that creating schemes like `market://` was a bad idea.

Please use an `<intent-filter>` that supports the `http://` scheme for some domain name you own and path that you control, so you can launch your activity that way. [Here is a recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139508/launching-an-android-application-from-the-browser/6139783#6139783) covering this topic.