# Launch custom Android application from WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an HTML file which is launching an app if I open it in the Android native browser,
but when I try to open the same in a WebView, it is not able to launch that application, and "Webpage not available" is shown. I think my WebView is not able to handle the scheme "my.special.scheme://" defined for the application.

I read [Launching an Android Application from the Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139508/launching-an-android-application-from-the-browser), but it does not cover information about launching an app from a WebView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe that WebView simply doesn't handle custom URI schemes.

The workaround is to override [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and manually test if the URL uses your URI scheme, launching your app and returning `true` if it matches, otherwise returning `false`.

Answer (score 8):

It's true, links with a custom URI scheme don't load automatically launch apps from a WebView.

What you need to do is add a custom WebViewClient to your WebView:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

and then in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), have the following code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView webView, final String url) {

    if (url.startsWith("my.special.scheme://")) {

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

        // The following flags launch the app outside the current app
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        activity.startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }  

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I perform an `ACTION_VIEW` with the URL to make the URL open in the default browser, which will do the redirecting to the concerning app (I had to fix this concerning payments via a bank app)