# Can I open whatsapp app from android webview

Tags: php, android, webview

I have made a web-view of a website. Now I want to share some data from my web-view to whatsapp app. I was able to open whatsapp web, but my client wants me to open whatsapp application instead of whatsapp web. How can I do that?

This is what I have done to open whatsapp web in my site:

```html
<a class="social-icon whatsapp" 
  href="javascript:popWin('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Product%20Name:-<?php echo $productName; ?>.%20Product%20link:-<?php echo $productUrl; ?>', 'whatsapp', 'width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0, location=no, status=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes');"
  title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Whatsapp') ?>" 
  data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
  <span><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Check out {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242230/launch-custom-android-application-from-webview}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use, its working for me:

Option First-

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello friend!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share</a>
```

Option Second-

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hello friend!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share</a>
```

Both options are working for me..

**If not working to your side then please update android version of your mobile phone & also update whatsapp version**

Comment: have you tried it with latest android system.. bcoz i tried it.. this link opens my whatsapp app properly

Comment: it open whatsapp web not whatsapp application

Answer (score 13):

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Put this code in your **mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()**. it will be working perfectly for all link like **tel:**, **whatsapp:** etc.

Comment: Thats work fine!! 
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
                if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: Working like a charm TQVM !

Answer (score 7):

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:") || url.startsWith("intent://") || url.startsWith("http://") ) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }

        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //     pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }



    });
```

my problem solves using this code.

Comment: webView.goBack(); this is what I was looking to remove the intermediate WhatsApp webpage. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use this and works ok. (@NSMedia-Solution)
Just put

> *'myWebView.goBack();'*

before return (For not navigate in whatsApp web)

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
                if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    myWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Great it helped `myWebView.goBack();` thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here I tried and it worked:

```
<a href="intent://send?text=Hello#Intent;scheme=whatsapp;package=com.whatsapp;end" class="button">Go to Whatsapp/>
```

See Chrome's docs about this [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#example).

Answer (score 0):

New version with updated shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin you con do this:

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?,
            ): Boolean {
                val url = request?.url.toString()
                /* INTENT WHATSAPP */
                if (url.startsWith("whatsapp://send")) {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    return true
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
            }
```