# how to load android app from a web page link?

Tags: android

I am trying to load an android application from html file when browsing the page with android browser.

I have tried like below

```
<a android:scheme="com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad">Click </a>
```

But without any avail...

I am also trying to pass a video link to the app.

Any has any idea..

I have seen this kind of link can be done in apple ios.

Comment: By "load", do you mean "start an already installed on the device Application" or do you mean "install an Application from a link on a web site"?

Comment: Similar type of question asked before : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042278/launch-android-application-from-a-browser-link?rq=1

Comment: Similar type of Question asked before : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042278/launch-android-application-from-a-browser-link?rq=1

Comment: already installed app

Answer (score 0):

And that's the Android way:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.troubi.kingofmath

At an Android device the user will be asked whether he'd like to open this app in the browser or Google Play.

Comment: Thanks...what if I wanted to pass a link to the app? Ie..a video link

Comment: Then you just give him the youtube link? :}

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but how do i do that ..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.troubi.kingofmath:www.youtube.com/xyxz?

Comment: @AbulHasnat Nope, you have to provide a separate youtube link starting with www.youtube.com/something-here