# Create Custom URL protocol in Android

Tags: android

How can I create a custom protocol in Android?

I have tried this code:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
<!-- open the app when a foo://www.example.com link is clicked -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="foo" />
</intent-filter>
```

Register this in Manifest file and call in browser like this foo://hello but it not open my app .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember having similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042278/1503155) a while back. Hope my solution will help you solve yours.
Add `android:exported="true"` and move `<data android:scheme="foo" />`
on top.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:exported="true">
<!-- open the app when a foo://www.example.com link is clicked -->
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="foo" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```