# How to deep linking my website to an app?

Tags: android, reactjs, deep-linking

I have a button in my website that when clicked needs to redirect to an app in App Store and Play Store.

I searched alot for the solution but i couldn't find how to connect a website to an app.

Hope someone tried the same thing and has the answer

Comment: At least on Android you can set it up in your manifest https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031955/create-custom-url-protocol-in-android

Comment: use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured that out once i posted the question.
This is how i did it:

'On your Android device, just open up the Android Market and select the app you want to share, then scroll down to "Share This Application" to either email, text or Facebook message it to someone in order to get the URL.'

Answer (score 0):

The way `DeepLinking` works is by defining the link in your android `AndroidManifesto` file. A `DeepLink` lets the `android OS` know that to open this `link` the `android OS` has not just the `browser` apps, instead this app that can also handle this link.

To create a `deepLink`, simply open the `AndroidManifesto` file located in:

```
<Project-Directory>/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and add the following to it:

```
<intent-filter android:label="nameThatShouldBeDisplayedInAppPreferenceMenu">
        <action android:name="uniqueNameOfActionForThisIntent" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
          android:host="www.yourhostname.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/yourPath"
          android:scheme="http" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi, i need to add the link in my website not in the app. I don't have an andorid manifesto. Thanks anyways