# Issue in open my application from browser url in android

Tags: php, android, browser, android-broadcast, deep-linking

Hello friends i wnat to open my application form browser url so in my menifest file below is my code

```
<activity
        android:name=".Registration"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data 
                android:scheme="rentalandroid"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and i want to open my application form Gmail application which is i receive one mail and inside that one button over here . so when i click on that button at that time my application should be open with registration screen which i set scheme for that so my **PHP developer** set url in on mail button click like below

**My browser url is**

```
http://secure.worldofrental.com/test/reg/36df6c69bf33fa39863e048a3018f899 


<a href='.base_url("test/reg/".$row['accsesskey']).'>testlink</a>
```

Using above code in my gmail i m not able to click that button so i can not navigate to my application so any idea how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url scheme should be `rentalandroid` for this to work:
Example: `rentalandroid://mywebsite.com`

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Registration"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data 
                    android:scheme="rentalandroid"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Lazy Ninja : your code is working , but now can you chekc my another question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317211/issue-in-using-custom-url-schema-application-open-option-dialog-not-open-through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317211/issue-in-using-custom-url-schema-application-open-option-dialog-not-open-through)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove category for view  :

```
<activity
        android:name=".Registration"
        android:exported="true" >

   <intent-filter>
       <data android:scheme="rentalandroid"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Haresh Chhelana : is there any change in PHP side ?

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya,Might be not but first try to check is it work or not.

Comment: Haresh Chhelana :  I done as per your suggestion but it is not working it is directly open browser site not my application

Comment: Haresh Chhelana : Still not working , it is directly navigate to my site

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663001/launching-custom-android-application-from-android-browser-chrome