# How to render website in android app?

Tags: android, android-browser

I have an website and want to open in android app.

When app opens my website url run and open in android app and i click on links on website it opens in this app.

So basically it works as a browser.

I am new as a android developer and made few basic native apps.

But i have no idea how to build this type of app.

Comment: you should use `WebView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch android application from a browser link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042278/launch-android-application-from-a-browser-link)

Answer (score -1):

in webview or web site

```
   <a href="yourapp://scan/">click me!</a>
```

in manifest :

```
   <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data
            android:host="scan"
            android:pathPrefix="/"
            android:scheme="yourapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```