# Android - Scheme URL - link redirect to app

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-studio, url-scheme

I need to open my android app when a QR code is scanned.

In the QR Code there is a link with a js script that open up the app.

In my Android Manifest I have add the `intent` however, when I visit the page the browser does not load the app. What am I missing?

Android:

```
    <!-- Test for URL scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="bbb" android:host="index"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- End Test for URL scheme -->
```

Js (testLink.php)

```
<script>
   window.location = 'bbb://index';
</script>
```

Comment: how exactly is this related to PHP?

Comment: just because the script is hosted in php file

Comment: when I scan qr code the browser opens testLink.php which contains the script to redirect to the app

Comment: Is your activity exported? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042278/launch-android-application-from-a-browser-link/13044911#13044911

Comment: For me everything works fine when I use <a href="bbb://">open app<\a>. But it's not working when I try to redirect the page using window.location

Comment: There are a lot of edge cases here, depending on browser type (Chrome vs. anything else) and version. If you're just looking for an easy way to make sure the app opens when the link is visited, I suggest giving a look to [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) and simply embed that link into your QR code

Comment: Yeah I can see that .. anyway find a solution using Cordova custom URL scheme plugin .. such a great plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `window.location` to `intent://index#Intent;scheme=bbb;end`

Comment: when I load the page with `window.location` in the android browser it does not do anything, it just reload the browser page. The app is not opening