# Launch Android App from WEB browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an internal app for my Company. Using Android Studio 2.2.3 as development environment, and AVD Emulator with Android 6.0 virtual device for testing.

We have a Web App that we use to create sales invoices. The Android App basically needs to receive an Invoice number, then it reads the Invoice data from a Web Service, and prints to a Bluetooth printer.

So basically, I've tried this 2 links in my web app:

```
<a href="company.printapp://INVOICE/1621696">PRINT INVOICE</a></div>
<a href="intent://INVOICE/1621696/#Intent;scheme=company.printapp;end">PRINT INVOICE</a>
```

Both throw the same error in the browser (testing in the emulator):

```
net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

My Manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="company.printapp">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="company.printapp" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package company.printapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;
import  android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        String scheme = data.getScheme();
        String host = data.getHost();
        List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
        String first = params.get(0); // "document type"
        String second = params.get(1); // "document No"
        BluetoothPrint(first,second);    
    }
}
```

Is there a solution that will work in both Chrome and Android's default web Browser? If not, I need it to work at least with Chrome.

Comment: Here is another way too, I hope it works on all web browsers...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042278/launch-android-application-from-a-browser-link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Guess I got my own answer after some more research:

It only works in Google Chrome but does the job in my case:

Links should look like:

```
<a href="intent://invoice/#Intent;scheme=company;package=company.printapp;S.doctype=FRA;S.docno=FRA1234;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com;end">PRINT INVOICE</a>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml the important part is:

```
...

package="company.printapp"
...

<!-- Allow web apps to launch My App -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="company" android:host="invoice" android:path="/"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

And finally this is how I get the parameters I pass in the Intent link (doctype and docno):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (parametros != null){
            String Doctype = parametros.getString("doctype");
            String DocNo = parametros.getString("docno");
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DocNo);
            textView.setText(DocNo);
            BluetoothPrint(Doctype,DocNo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only one that worked for me. Thanks man. Can you share your research here?