# How to get data user from openID onAndroid studio

Tags: java, android

I use webview to go url steam openid and can login on steam but i can get user information from steam openid

Comment: You want load url on explorer and login, when login success, explorer callback your app?

Comment: yes, callback my app and get information user.how can i do it?

Comment: You can open url on android browser by some event, last execute you can call back your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139508/launching-an-android-application-from-the-browser